# Ansible yaml dictionary reference to sibling elements

Tags: yaml, ansible

I'm trying to organize my variable definitions for ansible playbooks.

Example:

```
a_b: "a b"
a_c: "{{a_b}} c"
```

Works fine.

Trying to turn this into a dict:

```
a:
  b: "a b"
  c: "{{a.b}} c"
```

Sadly, this results in error that `a.b` is undefined.

Is it technically possible to refer to sibling elements within a dict?

Comment: I have same problem now. Can you please describe how you have solved your case? (if you can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference variables during the "init" variables phase. You can use `set_fact` to reference `{{ a.b }}`.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't help with your specific case, but if you simply trying to re-use value of a sibling variable, you can try use YAML anchor/alias to link to the value of the dictionary element you've defined earlier:

```
a:
  b: &anchor_b "a b"
  c: *anchor_b
```

This will result in:

```
a:
  b: "a b"
  c: "a b"
```

Here's an example where I re-use my tags dictionary to add tags to ec2 instances and also as uniqueness counter to create exact number of ec2 instances with particular set of tags:

```
create_ec2_instance:
  tags: &tags
    env: "prod"
    role: "database"
    cluster: "backend-db"
    owner: "me"
  count_tag: *tags
```

Comment: Have anything changed in the topic of references? Can they be used to concatenate values like the OP wanted? I have the same problem and this reference trick is quite nice but I do need to use reference as a integral part of the bigger value. Have anything been done in that field for last 2 years?

Comment: This should be much preferred approach..Documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#yaml-anchors-and-aliases-sharing-variable-values